# ESXI 5.1 not balancing CPU load across all cores/threads

Tags: load-balancing

I have 2x servers with 2x E5645 (6c/12t).

I am running own software which is processing millions of entries from database (database holds  compressed big chunk of data in each row, software is downloading it, decompressing and extracting all information), issue starts when I've installed ESXI 5.1 on those 2 servers.

It turned out that ESXI assigns each software thread to each available thread (so for example if software is using 17 threads, then ESXI will assign 17 CPU threads) without any balancing across all available CPU threads (17 threads are almost in 95% and 7 other CPU threads is 0%)...

This only happens on ESXI (I have other machines working without any issues and they are balancing all threads (for example 15 across 24 CPU threads), just Windows without ESXi)).

Is there any way to force ESXI with Windows to balance load across ALL CPU threads ???

(balancing works fine either on Windows 2008, 2012, Windows 7).

Each ESXi host has only 1 VM which has assigned all vCPU's.

Comment: The information is really scant here. How many virtual machines are you running on each of your 2 physical servers and how many vCPUs have they each been allocated? Also, have you read https://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/techpaper/VMware-vSphere-CPU-Sched-Perf.pdf

Comment: 1 VM - 24vCPU, I have used ESXi as it is much easier to deploy OS set which I am using for data computing.

Comment: @MMike1986 I think the issue here is that you don't *HAVE* 24 vCPUs - you have 12 that happen to be HT'ed - yes ESXi kinda-sorta sees them as CPUs but they're not full CPUs and it will treat them that way, i.e. they'll tie up main-CPU resources and be halted often. Basically no hypervisor will be tuned to behave as efficiently when dealing with HT as a bare-metal OS can be as they're designed to handle lots of smaller VMs rather than one big VM per host - also bear in mind that the actual hypervisor takes up a bit of CPU and memory too so you've not got all of the system to your VM anyway.

Comment: Is there any other hypervisor which can behave in similar way to bare-metal in terms of balancing load across all vCPUs ?  I know that I do not have 24 logical cores but for my application it doesn't matter as it can benefit from hyper-threading....

Comment: Just as an add-in to @Chopper3 s comment: http://blogs.vmware.com/vsphere/2014/02/overcommit-vcpupcpu-monster-vms.html

Comment: @MMike1986 no, they all have to work the same because of the architecture of servers vs. hypervisors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ESXi (and other hypervisors) are designed to control the CPU usage of guests, so that they don't occupy more resources than needed. It's what makes it possible to overcommit.

If the application isn't requesting more than 17 threads then you are probably better off with a bare-metal deployment instead. Maybe you can use containers in Windows Server 2016 when it is released.

Comment: Too bad that you can't select how do you want to balance CPU load :/ as hypervisors seems like a perfect way to go when I want to just add extra computing power :(  

Application can work with how many threads I want but it seems that 17-18 is the best to keep fans on low-medium level.

Comment: They are great yes, it's hyperthreading that we as sysadmins dislike as some people think of them as extra CPUs, they're really not and you'd be surprised how few applications really make use of them well.